# Shorthand for relative bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm often using such relative binding in my XAML files. Is there any way to shorten this chunk of code?

```
SomeProperty="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.SomeVMProperty}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit shorter:

```
SomeProperty="{Binding DataContext.SomeVMProperty
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
```

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the insight and editing my answer.

Comment: I mean that can I declare that like a variable or a macro?

Comment: The same way you would declare what you posted in your question.